# Equivalence relation of congruence in $\mathbb{R}$ regarded as a set of $1 \times 1$ matrices and the number of eq. classes

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to find the number of classes of the following equivalence relation in $\mathbb{R}$ seen as $1 \times 1$ matrices:

$A$ is congruent to $B$ $\iff \exists$ invertable $P: A=P^t B P$.

So for real numbers, we have $A=P^t B P \iff A=P^2B$ with $P\neq0$.

Thus we instantly see that $0$ has a class of its own.

Then if one sets $A=1$ and $B>0$, one gets $0<\frac{1}{B}=p^2$ and since $p^2$ is surjective on $\mathbb{R^+}$, all positive real numbers are a class.

The same procedure can be done for $A=-1$ with $B<0$.

So the equivalence classes are $[-1], [0], [1]$.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct. This is basically a proof, by the way, of [Sylvester's Law of Inertia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia) in dimension $1$, that is, of a classification of symmetric bilinear forms on a $1$-dimensional real vector space up to isomorphism.

Comment: Thank you for the link! This is exactly the topic I'm working on at the moment. Good to have the big picture.

Comment: You're welcome. It is instructive, by the way, to work out the same problem replacing $\Bbb R$ with $\Bbb C$.

Comment: For now, I replaced it with $\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: The answer, as you'll see, is quite different in flavor in that case!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is correct.${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$